# Get the most matching sentence in a list

Tags: python, list, match, sentence

How to find the most matching sentence in another sentence?

```
matchSentence = ["weather in", "weather at", "weather on"]
sentence = "weather on monday"

for item in matchSentence:
    ''' here get the index of the `item` 
    if all the words are in the `item` is in the `sentence` 
    '''
```

I'm looking for a function which will check whether all the words are present in the `sentence` or not.

> **Desired result is: 2**

Comment: use `in` operator

Comment: That was simple. I tried so many complex ways but didn't think about it.

Comment: But It's not working if I reorder the  words in `matchSentence`. is there any other way than just using 'in' operator?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "most matching", and I don't know what you mean about reordering the words or why you want to use .split(). But let me try: the result should be `2` because `matchSentence[2]` is `"weather on"`, and `sentence` contains `"weather"` and it *also* contains `"on"`? But not necessarily in order, and not necessarily consecutively?

Comment: what do you mean by reorder?

Comment: It needs to match every word in the test `item`? Or do you just want to find the one that has the most matching words? Do you really need the index, or just the words that matched? What should happen if nothing matches?

Comment: I meant not reordering exactly, `in` operator looks for only exact match. So I want a function which will check only all the words are present in the `sentence`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matchSentence = ["weather in", "weather at", "weather on"]
sentence = "weather on monday"

maxCount = 0
maxCntInd = -1
words1 = sentence.split()  # list of all words in sentence
wordSet1 = set(words1)

for item in matchSentence:
    ''' here get the index of the `item`
    if all the words are in the `item.split()` is in the `sentence`
    '''
    words2 = item.split()  # list of all words in item
    wordSet2 = set(words2)

    commonWords = len(wordSet2.intersection(wordSet1))
    if commonWords >= maxCount:
        maxCount = commonWords
        maxCntInd = matchSentence.index(item)

print(maxCntInd)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator:

```
matchSentence = ["weather in", "weather at", "weather on"]
sentence = "weather on monday"

for item in matchSentence:
    if item in sentence:
        print(matchSentence.index(item))
```

Output:

```
2
```

But it won't work in many cases, like

```
matchSentence = ["weather's on", "weather is very hot at", "leather on"]
sentence = "weather on monday"
```

---

---

---

**You can use the module [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) for cases like that:**

**Round 1:**

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

print(SequenceMatcher(None, "abc", "abc").ratio())
```

Output:

```
1
```

---

**Round 2:**

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

print(SequenceMatcher(None, "efg", "abc").ratio())
```

Output:

```
0
```

As you can see, `1` represents the most similarity possible (identical) and `0` is the least (no common characters at all).

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the most similar sentence is to count the number of times each word appears in the target sentence.

```
matchSentence = ["weather in", "weather at", "weather on"]
targetSentence = "weather on monday"
targetSentence_words = targetSentence.split(" ")

mostSimilarSentence = matchSentence[0]
mostSimilarSentenceScore = 0

for searchSentence in matchSentence:
    similarityScore = 0
    for word in searchSentence.split(" "):
        if word in targetSentence_words:
            similarityScore += 1

    print(f"Sentence: '{searchSentence}' got score: {similarityScore}")

    if similarityScore > mostSimilarSentenceScore:
        mostSimilarSentence = searchSentence
        mostSimilarSentenceScore = similarityScore

print(f"Most similar sentence: {mostSimilarSentence}")
print(f"Most similar sentence score: {mostSimilarSentenceScore}")
```